# MSMQ creation from CLI on Windows

Tags: windows, msmq, administration, windows-administration

Is there an easy way to create a private MSMQ from command line on Windows Workstation/Server flavors?

Appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You'd need to write your own app or script (or find one someone else has written).
There's nothing in the product to do it for you.

Comment: Don't hold your breath. There was an MS projecta couple of years ago to produce Powershell applets to manage MSMQ but I'm pretty sure that never made it to production.